# Laravel excel maatwebsite 3.1 import, date column in excel cell returns as unknown format number. How to solve this

Tags: laravel-excel

I am using Laravel 9 and Laravel-excel is 3.1. In the excel sheet, in one field only i need to take all datatype values. and also how to check whether it is date or integer value getting from excel sheet

In the excel sheet, in one field only i need to take all datatype values. and also how to check whether it is date or integer value getting from excel sheet